# Adding together JavaScript variables outside of functions

Tags: javascript

I'm a complete newbie to coding in general - attempting this after some reading and a few YouTube videos!

I have 2 separate Javascript functions that use basic addition to return numbers against an id in my HTML. These are working fine, but I want to use a third piece of Javascript to add both of the 'personal_items' and 'cash_total' numbers together and display them.

I have moved most of the variables outside of the functions to make them global so they can be used anywhere - but the HTML doesn't return a value for the calcTotalAssets() function.

As I said I'm completely new so any help would be much appreciated?

```
<script>
        var current_value_of_home;
        var current_value_other_properties;
        var personal_items;
        var current_accounts;
        var savings_accounts;
        var isa;
        var life_insurance;
        var family_friends;
        var cash_other;
        var cash_total;
        var total_assets;

        function calcPersonalItems(){
            current_value_of_home = document.getElementById('current_value_of_home').value;
            current_value_other_properties = document.getElementById('current_value_other_properties').value;
            personal_items = Number(current_value_of_home) + Number(current_value_other_properties);
            personal_items = personal_items.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
            document.getElementById('personal_items').innerHTML = "Personal Items = £"+personal_items;
        }

        function calcCashTotal(){
            current_accounts = document.getElementById('current_accounts').value;
            savings_accounts = document.getElementById('savings_accounts').value;
            isa = document.getElementById('isa').value;
            life_insurance = document.getElementById('life_insurance').value;
            family_friends = document.getElementById('family_friends').value;
            cash_other = document.getElementById('cash_other').value;
            cash_total = Number(current_accounts) + Number(savings_accounts) + Number(isa) + Number(life_insurance) + Number(family_friends) + Number(cash_other);
            cash_total = cash_total.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
            document.getElementById('cash_total').innerHTML = "Cash or Cash Equivalent = £"+cash_total;
        }

        function calcTotalAssets(){
            total_assets = Number(personal_items) + Number(cash_total);
            total_assets = total_assets.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
            document.getElementById('total_assets').innerHTML = "Assets = £"+total_assets;
        }

    </script>
```

HTML that is using the JavaScript - the output section at the bottom is supposed to show the final combined number;

```
 <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
                <h2>Personal Items</h2>
                <p>Current Value of Home: £<input id="current_value_of_home" type="number" min="0" max="5000000" step="1000" onchange="calcPersonalItems()"></p>
                <p>Current Value of Other Properties: £<input id="current_value_other_properties" type="number" min="0" max="10000000" step="1000" onchange="calcPersonalItems()"></p>
                <h3 id="personal_items"></h3>
                <h2>Cash or Cash Equivalent</h2>
                <p>Current Account(s): £<input id="current_accounts" type="number" min="0" max="5000000" step="100" onchange="calcCashTotal()"></p>
                <p>Savings Account(s): £<input id="savings_accounts" type="number" min="0" max="5000000" step="100" onchange="calcCashTotal()"></p>
                <p>ISA: £<input id="isa" type="number" min="0" max="5000000" step="100" onchange="calcCashTotal()"></p>
                <p>Life Insurance (cash value): £<input id="life_insurance" type="number" min="0" max="5000000" step="100" onchange="calcCashTotal()"></p>
                <p>Money Owed to You from Family/Friends: £<input id="family_friends" type="number" min="0" max="5000000" step="100" onchange="calcCashTotal()"></p>
                <p>Other: £<input id="cash_other" type="number" min="0" max="5000000" step="100" onchange="calcCashTotal()"></p>
                <h3 id="cash_total"></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:orange;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
                <p>Output</p>
                <h2 id="total_assets"></h3>
            </div>
```

Comment: why not make the variables global outside the function

Comment: Read up on how javascript variable scope works. A `var` inside a function is only available inside that function

Comment: remove the declaration `var` from inside the functions to outside , for all the variables you need to sum up .